# Use Excel VBA to compare and perform function

Tags: excel, vba

I am making a project for my small restaurant in excel VBA, I have designed a receipt and transfer form to sell to customers or transfer items to another department (departments: Store, Kitchen and Sales Point). I have a worksheet `"Inventory"` which contains all items from all departments their prices and available quantities.

However, I am having trouble with updating the available quantities automatically when the "close and save" or "Print" button is clicked i.e when items are sold or transferred.

Here is the code I have tried.

```
Sub updateinventory()
Dim invlastrow, reclastrow As Long
Dim ws1, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim itemName, itemQty, a, b

Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Inventory")
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Receipt")
invlastrow = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
reclastrow = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

 'MsgBox Cells(reclastrow, 3).Value


    Do While Cells(invlastrow, 3).Value <> ""
    itemName = Cells(invlastrow, 3).Value

        For b = 19 To reclastrow
            If itemName = Cells(reclastrow, 1) Then

            MsgBox (itemName)
             itemQty = Cells(invlastrow, 8).Value
             itemQty = itemQty - Cells(reclastrow, 3)
        End If
         Next b
        'MsgBox (itemQty)

     End If
Next a    
End Sub
```

Comment: If you're able to post a screenshot of part of the inventory sheet that this code refers to, then it would help a lot. Also, are you getting an error - or just some behavior other than what you expect?

Comment: "Dim itemName, itemQty, a, b" does not have a variable set. Also, you should always add "Option Explicit" to the top of your code (Before "Sub")

Comment: Ok thanks i will post a link to the file and the codes

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TE7Cbw0kOwtViiO5Kz4zyHwC-c79zKl_/view?usp=sharing